# Having emacs search for special ligatures

Tags: search, emacs, unicode, replace, ligature

I just noticed a whole bunch of typos in a compiled LaTeX document typed in emacs, stemming from me not noticing that when I pasted in some text from elsewhere, I accrued a lot of ligatures like ﬁ instead of fi.  I've done a search and replace to fix this particular instance, but it would be nice to be confident there weren't more of these.  Is there anything more wholesale I could do in emacs to find all such fixes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the entire document is expected to be in ASCII, then you could use a regexp search for anything outside that range:

<kbd>C-M-s</kbd> `[^` <kbd>C-j</kbd> <kbd>SPC</kbd> `-~]`

That is search for anything that is neither a newline (character code 10) nor anything between space (32) or tilde (126).  Any ligatures would be outside this range.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not real sure what you are asking, but you can easily Isearch for (or `query-replace` or `replace-string`) any Unicode chars that are ligatures, that is, that have `LIGATURE` as part of their Unicode character name. However, you must search for each of them separately (well, not really, but it is easiest to do that).

To search for a given ligature char, you use `C-x 8 RET` during Isearch, then type some part of the character name and complete that.

For this it ***really*** helps to use [***Icicles***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles), or at least some other completion enhancement that lets you complete a *substring* or other *regexp*.

With **Icicles** you have also [***progressive completion***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Progressive_Completion), which means that you can provide multiple substrings (more generally, regexps) to match.

For example, to search for the ligature whose Unicode character name is `LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FF` you can do the following:

```
C-s C-x 8 RET
```

That prompts you for the name of a Unicode char.  Type `ligature S-SPC` to match all whose names contain `ligature` (matching is case insensitive).  Then type `latin S-SPC` to narrow to just the latin ligatures.  Then type `small S-SPC` to narrow these to only the lowercase ligatures.  Then type `ffi` to get just the one you want.

```
C-s C-x 8 RET ligature S-SPC latin S-SPC small S-SPC ffi RET
```

The order in which you provide the multiple patterns is irrelevant.  And of course you do not *need* to use multiple patterns.  You could just as easily do it with a single regexp:

```
C-x C-x 8 RET latin.*small.*ligature.*ffi RET
```

If you use `C-s C-x 8 RET ligature S-TAB` (or `S-SPC` instead of `S-TAB`), you see all of the ligature characters (there are 517 of them).  If you use `C-s C-x 8 RET small.*ligature S-TAB` then you see all lowercase ligatures (there are 22 of them, including Arabic, Armenian, Cyrillic, Hebrew, and Latin).

Oh, and with **Icicles** you see not only the character names in buffer `*Completions*` -- you see also the characters themselves (WYSIWYG) next to their names.

(For `query-replace` etc. the procedure is the same as for Isearch.)

Comment: It is answers like this that remind me how little emacs I actually know.  Very informative, thanks!